# Get one element title and add this to another div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected">
        <a href="#" class="myClass" title="someTitle">..</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="myClass" title="someTitle1">..</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="myClass" title="someTitle2">..</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="firstDiv"></div>
```

When the `li a` is clicked I want to set it's `title` as the content in `#firstDiv`. I'm a newbie in this and I need help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what informations in a question might help to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the title attribute from the item clicked `$(this)` using `.attr('title')` and place the text in the div using `.html()` or `.text()`:

```
$('a.myClass').click(function(){
    $('#firstDiv').html($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

The only reason to use `e.preventDefauilt()` is if the page can scroll down, as a `#` bookmark link will spring to the top:

```
$('a.myClass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#firstDiv').html($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd do:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#firstDiv").text($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9bbtzgf/)